# Hide keyboard as soon as user touches DatePicker

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I have 2 EditText fields which I have the user fill out, followed by a DatePicker.  I am trying to hide the keyboard as soon as the user touches the DatePicker (as the keyboard is covering the save/cancel buttons.)

```
dpDate.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                hideSoftKeyboard();
                return false;
            }
        });

public void hideSoftKeyboard() {
        if(getCurrentFocus()!=null) {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
```

This is currently what I have, however, it does not appear to be working.  When I touch the DatePicker, click it, anything.. the keyboard will not go away.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:
The layout is as follows

```
Amount: (EditText)
Memo:   (EditText)
Date:   (DatePicker)
--------------------
Cancel            OK
```

When user touches that datepicker to change the date, I immediately want the keyboard to go away.

Comment: I suggest you to use a Button instead of an EditText.

Comment: ? Ill explain a little more in my question

Comment: EditText and DatePicker does not work well in harmony. Instead use a button, when clicked show date picker and set date picker result as button text.

Answer (score 0):

So you may need to just do `Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE` instead of just `INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE`.

Comment: No luck.  As a side note, the hideSoftKeyboard() does work on hiding the keyboard for other things, however, it just seems like the datepicker onTouch even isnt actually triggered

Comment: Try using `.setOnClickListener` and `OnClickListener()`

Comment: Right so just use change all those `onTouch` stuff to the respective `onClick` stuff!

Comment: Sorry i missed that part.  Cannot resolve symbol OnClickListener.

Comment: I read something about DatePicker you actually dont focus the datepicker itself, you focus the child views, jsut not sure how to do that ;)

Comment: The best thing for you to do, moving forward, is to open up a `DatePicker` via the clicking of an `EditText` or `Button`. I do both of those in some of my code, and it works wonderfully.

Comment: Thanks I am working on that now.  Right now, I have on click of EditText but it takes 2 clicks to open the dialog.